# WooCommerce Product Category Widget Behaviour (navigating to products)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget, categories, product

I am very new here and hope I am going about this write.  I searched topics but could not find one specifically about this.

I can't give a link to this because the site is in maintenance mode so I am going to try to explain it the best I can.

I have WooCommerce Product Category Widget setup as a sidebar navigation for a complex category setup.

**I have:**

Show hierarchy Only show children of the current category
Both checked on.

This works great when people are navigating the categories. But, as soon as they click on a product and it goes to a product page, the hierarchy closes in the sidebar.  I'd like to still see those subcategories open while on the product page.

I can't turn off the Children option because, while it's a partial solution, the the entire complex tree is showing at all times and it's just way too big.

Is there some method to keep that hierarchy open once you go to a product page?

Thanks for any info.